# `aliases` is not working with `root.dir` in knitr `opts_knit$set`?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

In the [knitr manual](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#package-options):

> aliases: (NULL) a named character vector to specify the aliases of
> chunk options

As my directory name is long, I want to use `aliases` as below:

```
knitr::opts_knit$set(aliases = c(mydir = 'E:/web/cel/ae repo/middle temp data/20190303'), root.dir = mydir,base.dir = mydir)
```

But I got the error: `can not find object mydir`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how the [package option `aliases`](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#package-options) works:

1. It allows you to define aliases for the *name* of an option, not shortcuts for option *values*.
2. In your sample code, you try to use the alias as value (see point 1) for a *package* option. Aliases are alternative names of *chunk* options.

To achieve what you're apparently trying to do, just define a new object `mydir` and use it when setting the package options:

```
mydir <- 'E:/web/cel/ae repo/middle temp data/20190303'
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = mydir, base.dir = mydir)
```

Comment: `knitr::opts_knit$set` is in `{r setup}`,should be the first beginning of .rmd?

Comment: The chunk name does not matter, but yes, I'd place this in the very first chunk.